# Where is the .xsession-errors file

Tags: xorg

I am runnig on ubuntu  18.10 but could find the Xsession files in Home directory:

```
$ ls -al  ~ | grep -i session
#did not return anything.
```

However the configuration indicate that they should be there.

```
$ grep -i 'xsession' /etc/X11/Xsession
# /etc/X11/Xsession
# global Xsession file -- used by display managers and xinit (startx)
# $Id: Xsession 967 2005-12-27 07:20:55Z dnusinow $
PROGNAME=Xsession
OPTIONFILE=/etc/X11/Xsession.options
SYSSESSIONDIR=/etc/X11/Xsession.d
USERXSESSION=$HOME/.xsession
USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
ALTUSERXSESSION=$HOME/.Xsession
ERRFILE=$HOME/.xsession-errors
  if ! ln -sf "$ERRFILE" "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}/xsession-$USER"; then
    message "warning: unable to symlink \"$TMPDIR/xsession-$USER\" to" \
             "\"$TMPDIR/xsession-$USER\"."
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some check didn't succeed on this line:

```
if (umask 077 && touch "$ERRFILE") 2> /dev/null && [ -w "$ERRFILE" ] &&
[ ! -L "$ERRFILE" ]
```

and now your .xsession-errors is instead in /tmp/file..... where dots represent a random name.

Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1156247/20275 for more info.